# ListView Horizontal PageScrollPhysics not align item center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some problem with Flutter.
I need align in ListView after scroll with pagescrollphysics in horizontal axis in center.
My container will go much left, and I don't understand how align item center in scrollview with axis horizontal direction.

I copi in my code. thanks to every all

Container of ListView:

```
Container(
  height: 150,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: ListView(
    physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: childreenSeries,
  ),
),
```

childreenSeries is an array of widget builded with this method:

```
List<Widget> serieBuilderHome({List<Serie> serie}) {
  List<Widget> childreen = [];
  if (serie != null) {
    this.series = serie;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    childreen.add(
      MyCard(context: context, serie: series[i]),
    );
  }
  return childreen;
}
```

MyCard is My Widget build like:

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCard({
  Key key,
  @required this.context,
  @required this.film,
  @required this.serie,
  @required this.category,
}) : super(key: key);

final BuildContext context;
final Serie serie;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '${serie.id}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${serie.name}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${serie.description}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '${serie.cast ?? []}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [
                  Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  Colors.deepOrange,
                  Colors.orange,
                  Colors.orangeAccent,
                ],
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
          );
        }
   }
```

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? Im facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

When I ran into this, it fixed when I *fully* reloaded the app onto the phone where I was debugging; apparently hot-reload doesn't exactly work intuitively in certain cases.